# Thermaltake PSU repair

Tags: power-supply

I have a thermaltake smart m650w power supply and one of the chips blew up (U3). Does anyone know the code for this part?[image]

Comment: probably a TopSwitch .Not too expensive .these chips are not reliable when you have spikes on the mains.

Comment: Crop the photo before uploading, man. Crop the photo!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably one of these: -

[image]

<sub>Image source: [Power Integrations - TinySwitch-LT Data Sheet](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/documents/tinyswitch-lt_family_datasheet.pdf)</sub>

Package similarity: -

[image]